# Spring form binding how to do it ? Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

here is my form :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="fooDTO">
fooCountry: 
<form:select path="country">
  <form:options items="${countries}" itemLabel="shortName" itemValue="id"/> 
</form:select>
```

here is the backing pojo :

```
public class FooDTO
{
  private Country country;
 //getters and setters present
}
```

The selected option defaults to the country value in fooDTO, which is good. But the binding then fails when submitting the form - I get the aformentioned error, do I have to register a custom editor in a binder, or is there a simpler method ? Country is pretty much as you'd expect, and countries is indeed a list of countries populated in the controller ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring 3 introduced the Converter SPI which makes this quite easy.  Have a look at 6.5 in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion)

Taking source from the docs and putting in your country, you would do something like

```
package my.converter;

final class StringToCountry implements Converter<String, Country> {
    public Country convert(String source) {
        return // whatever you do to get a country from your string
    }
}
```

Then in the xml config you would configure the converter

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="my.converter.StringToCountry"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As GriffeyDog pointed out, you may want to put the country id in for the select path so you can get the Country by ID or something instead of whatever is returned by toString() of your Country object.

Comment: and for _java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.OneToMany java.util.Set<com.machinet.myapp.MyEntity>_ ?

Answer (score 7):

Change your path to `<form:select path="country.id">`. That will at least give you the `id` field popluated inside the `Country` object upon posting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Spring sees an instance of `String`, but knows that it needs an instance of `Country`.  It doesn't "know" by default how to get from one to the other.

I haven't used Spring form binding before, but this looks like the same issue that can be encountered in the Spring framework itself.  And in the latter case you solve it by [registering a `PropertyEditor` implementation for your class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion), so I expect a similar approach would work here.

Comment: yeah, I am digging through that now. Sometimes the spring docs are rather impenetrable, they offer almost too many options ...

Answer (score 1):

In Spring you can also use ConversionService

Here's the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-FormattingConversionService

You'll need to implement Converter interface.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my solution:

```
public class CompanyIdToInstanceConverter implements Converter<String, Company> {

@Autowired
CompanyService _companyService;

@Override
public Company convert(final String companyIdStr) {
    return _companyService.find(Long.valueOf(companyIdStr));
}

}
```

This converts company ID from select into Company by getting it from DB.

If you have any additional questions please ask, because now I'm doing similar things in my app :)

Additionally you need to add to app-context:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

<!-- conversion service -->
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>toryLabelConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="pl.greenpath.converter.CompanyIdToInstanceConverter"></bean>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an MVC application, please see this Spring Source forum link for how to configure your application context. The details are at the bottom of the thread.

The conversionService class is different with MVC and you need to specify mvc:annotation-driven (even if you are not using annotations).

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84003-Converters-no-matching-editors-or-conversion-strategy-found

You will find the specifics in the Spring documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-formatting-mvc