# Persisting bi-directional Many to many relationship columns (Join table)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jpa

I am having trouble while accessing join table related data after user has provided same.

Here is the related code

ServiceCategory.java (model class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "servicecategory")
public class ServiceCategory  extends BaseEntity {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
@Column(name = "servicecatname", nullable = false)
private String serviceCatName;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 200)
@Column(name = "servicecatdescription", nullable = false)
private String serviceCatDescription;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 500)
@Column(name = "servicecatimagefilename", nullable = false)
private String serviceCatImageFileName;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "servicecategory_employee", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "servicecatid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "empid") })
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

@Transient
private MultipartFile serviceCatImage;

private Boolean deleted;

public String getServiceCatName() {
    return serviceCatName;
}

public void setServiceCatName(String serviceCatName) {
    this.serviceCatName = serviceCatName;
}

public String getServiceCatDescription() {
    return serviceCatDescription;
}

public void setServiceCatDescription(String serviceCatDescription) {
    this.serviceCatDescription = serviceCatDescription;
}

public String getServiceCatImageFileName() {
    return serviceCatImageFileName;
}

public void setServiceCatImageFileName(String serviceCatImageFileName) {
    this.serviceCatImageFileName = serviceCatImageFileName;
}

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public MultipartFile getServiceCatImage() {
    return serviceCatImage;
}

public void setServiceCatImage(MultipartFile serviceCatImage) {
    this.serviceCatImage = serviceCatImage;
}

public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}



}
```

Employee.java (model class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
@Column(name = "empfirstname", nullable = false)
private String empFirstName;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
@Column(name = "emplastname", nullable = false)
private String empLastName;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
@Column(name = "empdesignation", nullable = false)
private String empDesignation;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employeetypeid", nullable = true)
private EmployeeType employeeType;

//@Size(min = 3, max = 500)
@Column(name = "employeeImageFileName", nullable = false)
private String employeeImageFileName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="employees")
private List<ServiceCategory> serviceCategories = new ArrayList<>();

private Boolean deleted;

@Transient
private MultipartFile employeeImage;

public String getEmpFirstName() {
    return empFirstName;
}

public void setEmpFirstName(String empFirstName) {
    this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
}

public String getEmpLastName() {
    return empLastName;
}

public void setEmpLastName(String empLastName) {
    this.empLastName = empLastName;
}

public String getEmpDesignation() {
    return empDesignation;
}

public void setEmpDesignation(String empDesignation) {
    this.empDesignation = empDesignation;
}

public String getEmployeeImageFileName() {
    return employeeImageFileName;
}

public void setEmployeeImageFileName(String employeeImageFileName) {
    this.employeeImageFileName = employeeImageFileName;
}

public EmployeeType getEmployeeType() {
    return employeeType;
}

public void setEmployeeType(EmployeeType employeeType) {
    this.employeeType = employeeType;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<ServiceCategory> getServiceCategories() {
    return serviceCategories;
}

public void setServiceCategories(List<ServiceCategory> serviceCategories) {
    this.serviceCategories = serviceCategories;
}

public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}

public MultipartFile getEmployeeImage() {
    return employeeImage;
}

public void setEmployeeImage(MultipartFile employeeImage) {
    this.employeeImage = employeeImage;
}


}
```

employeeadd.jsp

```
<section class="inner-banner">
<div class="container">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Employees</a></li>
        <li class="active">${ACTION} Employee</li>

    </ol>
</div>
</section>


<!-- form section-->
<section class="formSection">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="sectionHeading">${ACTION} Employee</h1>
        <div class="divider"></div>

        <form:form modelAttribute="employee" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <form:label path="empFirstName">Employee First Name<em class="mandatory">*</em></form:label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <form:input path="empFirstName" cssClass="form-control"  />
                            <form:errors class="alert alert-danger" path="empFirstName" /> 
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <form:label path="empLastName">Employee Last Name<em class="mandatory">*</em></form:label>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <form:input path="empLastName" cssClass="form-control"  />
                        <form:errors class="alert alert-danger" path="empLastName" />
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <form:label path="empDesignation">Employee Designation<em class="mandatory">*</em></form:label>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <form:input path="empDesignation" cssClass="form-control"  />
                        <form:errors class="alert alert-danger" path="empDesignation" /> 
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <form:label path="employeeType">Employee Type<em class="mandatory">*</em></form:label>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                           <form:select path="employeeType.id"  class="selectpicker" multiple="false">
                                    <form:option value="0" label="   -- Please Select --" />
                                    <form:options items="${employeeTypeList}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="employeeType"/>
                           </form:select>
                        <form:errors class="alert alert-danger" path="employeeType" />
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <form:label path="serviceCategories">Service Categories<em class="mandatory">*</em></form:label>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">                     
                           <form:select path="serviceCategories" class="selectpicker" multiple="true">
                                    <form:options items="${serviceCategoriesList}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="serviceCatName"/>
                           </form:select>
                        <form:errors class="alert alert-danger" path="serviceCategories" />
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <form:label path="employeeImage">Upload Employee Image<em class="mandatory">*</em></form:label>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input name="employeeImage" type="file">
                        <form:errors class="alert alert-danger" path="employeeImage" />
                </div>                  
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <c:if test="${ACTION == 'Edit'}">
               <form:hidden path="employeeImageFileName" />
            </c:if>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <!-- <button type="submit" class=" orangebtn btn mtop20">
                    Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right left"></i>
                </button> -->
                <form:button type="submit" class=" orangebtn btn mtop20">Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right left"></i></form:button>
            </div>
        </div>          

    </form:form>

</div>
```

EmployeeController.java

```
    /* This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
     saving employee in database. It also validates the user input*/

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/add" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployee(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model, Map<String, Object> map,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        boolean isError = false;

        logger.debug("Entered saveEmployee method");
        logger.debug("employee.getEmpFirstName() : "
                + employee.getEmpFirstName());
        logger.debug("employee.getEmpLastName() : "
                + employee.getEmpLastName());
        logger.debug("employee.getEmpDesignation() : "
                + employee.getEmpDesignation());
        logger.debug("employee.getEmployeeImage().getSize() : "
                + employee.getEmployeeImage().getSize());
        logger.debug("employee.getEmployeeType() : "
                + employee.getEmployeeType());
        logger.debug("employee.getServiceCategories() : "
                + employee.getServiceCategories());
        logger.debug("employee.getEmployeeType().getId() : "
                + employee.getEmployeeType().getId());
        logger.debug("employee.getServiceCategories().size() : "
                + employee.getServiceCategories().size());
}
```

When the user submits data and selects service categories, the following is printed in logs

```
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,679 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - Entered saveEmployee method
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,679 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getEmpFirstName() : fsddf
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,680 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getEmpLastName() : sdfsdsfdsdf
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,680 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getEmpDesignation() : sdfsdfsd
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,681 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getEmployeeImage().getSize() : 252227
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,681 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getEmployeeType() : com.abc.model.EmployeeType@56261adf
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,681 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getServiceCategories() : []
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,682 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getEmployeeType().getId() : 1
DEBUG   2015-08-06 11:07:36,682 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-3] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - employee.getServiceCategories().size() : 0
```

I am not sure why employee.getServiceCategories().size() is zero, even if I select multiple service categories from the view.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**UPDATE**

While debugging I also tried to print the value of BindingResult result and it is showing me following in logs

```
  DEBUG   2015-08-06 14:59:20,686 [http--127.0.0.1-8080-4] com.abc.controller.EmployeeController  - result : org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'employee' on field 'serviceCategories': rejected value [15,17]; codes [typeMismatch.employee.serviceCategories,typeMismatch.serviceCategories,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.serviceCategories,serviceCategories]; arguments []; default message [serviceCategories]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'serviceCategories'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.abc.model.ServiceCategory] for property 'serviceCategories[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Comment: Your problem really has nothing to do with JPA.  The selected service categories are not being bound by Spring MVC on the Employee.  My personal preference is to not use JPA entities directly in the view layer.  You'll run into lazy loading exceptions and painful design problems.  You're better off with a "View Model" that is different from your ORM.

Comment: @SteveHall Thanks for your comment. But how do I bind spring mvc on employee in this case? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. There was an issue in data binding as spring couldn't get value of list employee.serviceCategories from serviceCategories variable.

I did some RnD (mainly refereed [Spring form binding how to do it ? Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416987/spring-form-binding-how-to-do-it-cannot-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-strin) and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-formatting-mvc) and made the following changes in my controller

```
    @InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("in binding for service categories");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "serviceCategories",
            new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class) {
                @Override
                protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                    String serviceCategoryId = (String) element;
                    logger.info("service category id = " + serviceCategoryId);
                    List<ServiceCategory> serviceCategoryList = null ;
                    if (serviceCategoryId != null) {
                        logger.info("found object");
                        Map<String, Object> whereClauses = new HashMap<>();
                        whereClauses.put(Constants.ID, serviceCategoryId);

                        try {
                            serviceCategoryList = serviceCategoryService.findServiceCategories
                                        (whereClauses, null , null, Constants.ACTIVE);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);                                
                        }                       
                    }
                    return serviceCategoryList;
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: You may also want to consider using the org.springframework.core.convert SPI.  It would provided you a global convention for converting your ServiceCategory objects.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Converter-API