# How to solve "Failed to convert property value[...]"

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

So I have a form with a dropdown in Spring MVC:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" action="registerVerify" method="post">
<!-- Other fields-->
<spring:message code="register.country" />
        <form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
        <br/>
</form:form>
```

Which is populated by this controller:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "registerForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("countryList", cDao.getCountryMap());
        model.addAttribute("companyList", cpDao.getCompanyMap());
        return "login/registerForm";
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "registerVerify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String makeRegistration(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
            model.addAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user", result);
            return "redirect:registerForm";
        }
        if (dao.add(user)) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:registerForm";
        }

    }
// Service classes bellow
```

I've made some converters

```
package br.com.sirious.energyquality.converters;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

import br.com.sirious.energyquality.dao.CompanyDao;
import br.com.sirious.energyquality.models.Company;

public class IdToCompanyConverter implements Converter<String, Company>{

    @Autowired
    CompanyDao dao;

    @Override
    public Company convert(String id) {
        return dao.getCompanyByID(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }

}
```

And I've set My WebMVCConfig (and WebApplicationInitializer, and spring-context...)

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry){
        registry.addConverter(new IdToCompanyConverter());
    }


}
```

But I still get "Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [br.com.sirious.energyquality.models.Company] for property 'Company'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [br.com.sirious.energyquality.models.Company] for property 'Company': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

I've checked on many similar posts but none solved the problem. Can someone diagnose what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following *ConverterRegistry* method:

```
<S,T> void addConverter(Class<S> sourceType,
                    Class<T> targetType,
                    Converter<? super S,? extends T> converter)
```

Which will result in:

```
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry){
    registry.addConverter(String.class, Company.class, new IdToCompanyConverter());
}
```

Comment: I added that to my MainInitializer (WebApplicationInitializer class) and no luck. Still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on the path of the form:select tag:

```
<spring:message code="register.country" />
        <form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
```

In order to map to the object that is used as reference, the path has to be the id of the object, so path will be: **Country.id.**

The idea is similar to what is said here: [Spring form binding how to do it ? Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416987/spring-form-binding-how-to-do-it-cannot-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-strin)

Also, xuesheng has added some interesting information about registering the converter without using web.xml.